# Reading a JSON string | TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, string, typeerror

I'm trying to create a program that will read in a JSON string through the GUI and then use this to perform additional functions, in this case breaking down a mathematical equation. At the moment I am getting the error:

> "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

and I have no idea why.

The JSON I am trying to read in is as follows:

```
{
"rightArgument":{
"cell":"C18",
"value":9.5,
"type":"cell"
},
"leftArgument":{
"rightArgument":{
"cell":"C3",
"value":135,
"type":"cell"
},
"leftArgument":{
"rightArgument":{
"cell":"C4",
"value":125,
"type":"cell"
},
"leftArgument":{
"cell":"C5",
"value":106,
"type":"cell"
},
"type":"operation",
"operator":"*"
},
"type":"operation",
"operator":"+"
},
"type":"operation",
"operator":"+"
}
```

```
import json
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

data = ""
list = []

def readText():
    mtext=""
    mtext = strJson.get()
    mlabel2 = Label(myGui,text=mtext).place(x=180,y=200)
    data = mtext

def mhello():
    _getCurrentOperator(data)

def _getCurrentOperator(data):
    if data["type"] == "operation":

        _getCurrentOperator(data["rightArgument"])        
        _getCurrentOperator(data["leftArgument"]) 
        list.append(data["operator"])
    elif data["type"] == "group":
        _getCurrentOperator(data["argument"]) 
    elif data["type"] == "function":
        list.append(data["name"]) # TODO do something with arguments
        for i in range(len(data["arguments"])):
            _getCurrentOperator(data["arguments"][i])
    else:
        if (data["value"]) == '':
            list.append(data["cell"])
        else:
            list.append(data["value"])

print(list)

myGui = Tk()
strJson = StringVar()


myGui.title("Simple Gui")
myGui.geometry("400x300")

label = Label(text = 'Welcome!').place(x=170,y=40)
btnStart = Button(myGui,text='Start',command=mhello).place(x=210,y=260)
btnRead = Button(myGui,text='Read text',command=readText).place(x=210,y=200)
txtEntry = Entry(myGui, textvariable=strJson).place(x=150,y=160)
btnOptions = Button(myGui, text = "Options").place(x=150,y=260)

myGui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you give the whole stacktrace?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply :) Whilst running the program, the Call Stack window remains empty

Comment: The question should have originally been closed, if not as a duplicate, then due to lacking an appropriate [mre]. It's also important to try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) code before posting a question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are never parsing the string to a dictionary (json object). Change `data = mtext` to: `data = json.loads(mtext)` You should also add `global data` to the readText method

Comment: @Rawing You mean in mhello right? Cause _getCurrentOperator already gets it by parameter.

Comment: OK TY Will edit. I'm always using OOP so I'm not familiar with global.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Having made these changes I'm still experiencing the exact same error

Comment: @BillyDawson: Did you add `global data` at the top of the `readText` function?

Comment: I'd put global data at the start of the program rather than in readText. Having done this there are now no errors but the program doesn't output the broken down equation, nothing appears at all.

Comment: @BillyDawson: Why would you expect anything to "appear"? You're only appending stuff to your `list` variable. You aren't outputting anything, nor are you modifying the GUI.

Comment: I'd originally wanted the print(list) to output stuff for testing purposes, I've managed to fix that now by putting it in the right place. The code works perfectly now! Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 6):

`TypeError: string indices must be integers` means an attempt to access a location within a string using an index that is not an integer. In this case your code (line 18) is using the string `"type"` as an index. As this is not an integer, a `TypeError` exception is raised.

It seems that your code is expecting `data` to be a dictionary. There are (at least) 3 problems:

1. You are not decoding ("loading") the JSON string. For this you should use `json.loads(data)` in the `readText()` function. This will return the dictionary that your code expects elsewhere.
2. `data` is a global variable with value initialised to an empty string (`""`). You can not modify a global variable within a function without first declaring the variable using the `global` keyword.
3. The code builds a list by appending successive items to it, however, that list is not used elsewhere. It is printed after the definition of `_getCurrentOperator()` but this is before any processing has been done, hence it is still empty at that point and `[]` is displayed. Move `print(list)` to `mhello()` after`_getCurrentOperator()`. (BTW using `list` as a variable name is not advised as this shadows the builtin `list`)

You can revise `readText()` to this:

```
def readText():
    global data
    mtext=""
    mtext = strJson.get()
    mlabel2 = Label(myGui,text=mtext).place(x=180,y=200)
    data = json.loads(mtext)
```

Comment: "It seems that your code is expecting data to be a dictionary." +1

Answer (score 6):

sometimes you need to use json.loads again..
this worked for me..

```
jsonn_forSaleSummary_string = json.loads(forSaleSummary)  //still string
jsonn_forSaleSummary        = json.loads(jsonn_forSaleSummary_string)
```

finally!! json

Comment: I think what may be happening here is that your json is surrounded by quotes, while the quotes inside are escaped `"{\\"key\\":\\"value\\"}"`. In that case, the initial json.loads removes the surrounding quotes and the escape characters, leaving a json object. The second json.loads then parses the json object.