# some random error in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I get some random error while printing results from python dictionary

code

```
response_str = {'personal_emails': [{'email_address': 'hi'}]}


email_f = []
email_s = []
email_h = []

email_s = response_str["personal_emails"]
#print response_str
#print email_s
for email_1 in email_s:
    print email_1
    if email_1["confidence_score"] == "50":
        print email_1["email_address"]
        email_f.append(email_1["email_address"])
    if email_1["confidence_score"] == "75":
        print email_1["email_address"]
        email_s.append(email_1["email_address"])
    if email_1["confidence_score"] == "100":
        print email_1["email_address"]
        email_h.append(email_1["email_address"])
```

Error:

```
  File "emai_sep.py", line 13, in <module>
    if email_1["confidence_score"] == "50":
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839195/reading-a-json-string-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers)?

Comment: print `type(email_1)`  just before the error :-)

Comment: Clearly response_str is not what you show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is because of this line:

```
email_s.append(email_1["email_address"])
```

This is the list the iterator runs on, and during the iterations you change it.

when I ran this code after comment that line out it ran smoothly.

So, my suggestion is you use another list to append 'email_addresses' to, like this:

```
response_str = {'personal_emails': [{'email_address': 'karogers826@gmail.com', 'confidence_score': '75'}, {'email_address': 'plushpalcreations@gmail.com', 'confidence_score': '50'}, {'email_address': 'poet@gmail.com', 'confidence_score': '50'}, {'email_address': 'kristen.the.poet@gmail.com', 'confidence_score': '75'}]}


email_f = []
email_s = []
email_h = []
email_s_NEW = [] # NEW LIST

email_s = response_str["personal_emails"]
#print response_str
#print email_s
for email_1 in email_s:
    print email_1
    if email_1["confidence_score"] == "50":
        print email_1["email_address"]
        email_f.append(email_1["email_address"])
    if email_1["confidence_score"] == "75":
        print email_1["email_address"]
        email_s_NEW.append(email_1["email_address"]) # APPEND TO THIS LIST
    if email_1["confidence_score"] == "100":
        print email_1["email_address"]
        email_h.append(email_1["email_address"])
```

Comment: Nice catch, Gal.  An error like this is is a good reminder to use meaningful variable names.

Comment: Thanks, and you're right that's very important :) and I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Right, I was testing in after running the loop and got the strings get into the same list.