# Python book example error: "string incides must be integers"

Tags: python, typeerror

Scripting Language: Python 3.6

Reference Book: Python Data Visualization Cookbook [Milovanović 2013-11-25]

---

Teaching myself Python Data Visualization

When I execute code from book

```
import requests

url = 'https://github.com/timeline.json'

r = requests.get(url)
json_obj = r.json()

repos = set() # we want just unique urls
for entry in json_obj:
    try:
        repos.add(entry['repository']['url'])
    except KeyError as e:
        print ("No key %s. Skipping..." % (e))

from pprint import pprint 
pprint(repos)
```

I get error

```
repos.add(entry['repository']['url'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How to troubleshoot? When I see [similar threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839195/reading-a-json-string-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers), I draw a blank

Is the code from book even correct?

**[As an aside, where did set() in `repos = set()` come from?]**

Please point me in the right direction

Comment: From the json_obj:
Hello there, wayfaring stranger. If you're reading this then you probably didn't see our blog post a couple of years back announcing that this API would go away: http://git.io/17AROg Fear not, you should be able to get what you need from the shiny new Events API instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API being used is obsolete.  The following code uses the current API:

```
import requests
url = 'https://api.github.com/events' # New API URL

r = requests.get(url)
json_obj = r.json()

repos = set() # we want just unique urls
for entry in json_obj:
    try:
        repos.add(entry['repo']['url'])  # Key change. 'repo' not 'repository'
    except KeyError as e:
        print ("No key %s. Skipping..." % (e))

from pprint import pprint 
pprint(repos)
```

As others have pointed out `set()` creates a set object, which can only contain unique values.  Example:

```
>>> set([1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6])
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

Note that a set is unordered, so don't depend on the items being sorted as they seem to be in the example.

Answer (score 2):

If you print the json_obj you get this:

```
{'message': 'Hello there, wayfaring stranger. If you’re reading this then you pr
obably didn’t see our blog post a couple of years back announcing that this API 
would go away: http://git.io/17AROg Fear not, you should be able to get what you
 need from the shiny new Events API instead.', 'documentation_url': 'https://dev
eloper.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-public-events'}
```

So this link seems to be old and you will have to look the new one up.

For your second question:
`set()` is a data container similar to `dict()` and `list()`. sets are similar to lists in that they store a number of objects. The biggest differences are:

- sets are not sorted (like dictionaries)
- sets only contain unique items

You can find more info in the python documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

I hope this helps, good luck with your learning.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you get some answers to your questions...

The `TypeError: string indices must be integers` is because, since the API is down, `entry` is now only a string (`u'documentation_url'`), and when `entry['repository']` it raises an error because, with strings, you can only `get` the n-th character **from an integer n** (you can't get the *repository-th* character).

**[As an aside, where did set() in repos = set() come from?]**

When you do `repos = set()` you're only creating an empty set object an assigning it to `repos`. You would fill it later with `repos.add(entry['repository']['url'])`

Answer (score 1):

The `entry` object you are trying to access is a string, so you cannot access it with non-integer indices. I tried running your code and the url seems to be down or blocked because of too many requests, so this might be the reason why `entry` ends up becoming a string object.

the `repos = set()` means that, when you add new urls to `repos` it will ignore cases where that url is already in the set so you don't end up with duplicates. If you used `repos = []` instead you would have to manually check for duplicates at every insertion (unless you wanted to allow duplicates).

You can read more about the set() data structure here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html